# VB.Net writing to cell strange behavior

Tags: excel, vb.net

I have some values I'm writing to excel but they are not being written. The strange part is that if I read the cell and display the value in a MsgBox it is displayed. So the value is in the cell, but is not because it's empty.

```
Dim xlApp As New Application
Dim xlBook As Workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add()
Dim xlSheet As Worksheet = CType(xlBook.ActiveSheet, Worksheet)

Dim xlRange As Range = xlSheet.Range("A1")
xlRange.Value = "Starting...."
-----
-----
xlSheet.Range("A3").Value = AuthToken.ToString()
MsgBox("In Cell A3 you have written: " & xlSheet.Range("A3").Value)
```

[image: Excel]

Any ideas?

**Improvement**

I managed to make it work but the solution is not the best, I don't want to be using With every time I want to write something...

```
With xlSheet
    Range("A1").Value = "Starting"
    Range("A2").Value = Token
End With
```

Comment: You highlight A1, not A3.  Any chance the font is white?

Comment: As the msgbox is open I can't select the cell A3 but there's something written there as well.
Dim xlRange As Range = xlSheet.Range("A1")
        xlRange.Value = "Starting...."

My first guess was that the font was white but it's not. The cell is empty.

Comment: Are you looking at the right spreadsheet?

Comment: There's only one sheet in the workbook...

Comment: Looks like you're writing to a new (invisible) Excel instance.